# In LLVM IR, how to get the pointee Value of a pointer type?

Tags: llvm

I am writing a pass to do constant folding.
Like this C code:

```
int a = 4;
int b = a + 5;
```

I want to transform it to:

```
int b = 4 + 5;
```

But the first segment of code will generate an instruction for `int a`:

```
store i32 4, i32* %a, align 4
```

How can I get the Value "%a" from this pointer "i32* %a" in my Pass?
So that I can replace all use of the Value %a to the ConstantInt ?

Comment: Are you attempting to modify the GlobalVariable "a" at runtime or during your pass?

Comment: No, "a" is a stack memory location, allocated by `alloca`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`load`](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#load-instruction) instruction:

```
%1 = load i32* %a, align 4
```

Comment: How can I load the address in my Pass ?

Comment: The value of `%a` is unknown unless you run the program. A Pass doesn't run the program. It simply inspects and/or transform your program.

Comment: Oh I see. But actually `%a` is a "constant". So is there any other method to do this constant folding ? I know a constant `4` is stored into the address, I want to replace all the use of `%a` to `4` .

Comment: I guess you might have to implement that yourself. Memorize the value from `store` and use it as a replacement in `load`. This might get complicated though, because `%a` could be loaded into `%1`, `%2`, ... and chains of other variables.

Answer (score 0):

For that, first you need to get all the uses of Value %a

```
Val.user_begin() to val.user_end() via Value::const_user_iterator it
```

and check if there Stored instruction is there and only const is stored

```
 if (const StoreInst* store = dyn_cast<StoreInst>(*it))
```

then you can replace all instances with that const.
Note: this is vary simple algo for inst that you have given

a = 5; b = a +4;